# Is there some way I can get ember-cli to build only the styles?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm creating a bunch of themes by passing variables into ember-cli. Is there some reasonable way for me to configure Ember to only do the CSS build?

Comment: You could write addon to drop everything except styles when flag is set but as far as I know build pipeline also removes dist folder. So you would have to handle that too.

Comment: I would recommend you to modify the build-pipeline that you build all styles at once, and then automatically duplicate the build output rather then run the build pipeline multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need `ember-cli` if you are just building out the css? Couldn't you build out the themes with [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) or [Less](http://lesscss.org/) or [PostCSS](https://github.com/postcss/postcss)? Perhaps I'm not fully understanding the entire use case here but if you're just trying to compile styles, one of these tools may be of better use. If you must stay inside Ember, you can leverage addons like [ember-cli-sass](https://github.com/aexmachina/ember-cli-sass) to make this process much easier.

Comment: Some ember addons styles get imported during the build.